# Unit testing with NUnit and Console

Tags: .net, unit-testing, console, nunit, pdcurses

I've been playing around with the curses sharp library (a c# wrapper for pdcurses), writing some unit test code to get a handle on the api and how it works, and I've come up with a question.

I can run curses sharp from within a DLL (so that nUnit can test it), using the following code:

```
        bool consoleAllocated = AllocConsole();
        if (!consoleAllocated)
            throw new Exception("Unable to allocate a new console.");

        Curses.InitScr();

        Stdscr.Add(4, 6, "This is a test title");

        Curses.EndWin();

        FreeConsole();
```

AllocConsole and FreeConsole are extern's imported from kernel32.

What I would like to do is be able to read the console output from position 4,6 to a string so as to programmatically check that the string I've entered has been output correctly. It would be pretty important to be able to do checks like this in order to create a curses-style app using TDD for instance.

I've looked over the Curses and Stdscr objects (both Curses Sharp objects), and the Console object (from the windows library) and haven't been able to find a way yet.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find an answer, in case anyone was interested I've included the code below.  It's messy, as I haven't cleaned it up yet, but it should serve as an example as to how to do this.

Thanks to [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) for their excellent signature collection.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
        [Out]StringBuilder lpCharacter, uint nLength, COORD dwReadCoord,
        out uint lpNumberOfCharsRead);

    const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }

    [Test]
    public void WriteTitle()
    {
        bool consoleAllocated = AllocConsole();
        if (!consoleAllocated)
            throw new Exception("Unable to allocate a new console.");

        Curses.InitScr();

        Stdscr.Add(4, 6, "This is a test title");
        Stdscr.Refresh();

        IntPtr stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        uint length = 20;
        StringBuilder consoleOutput = new StringBuilder((int)length);
        COORD readCoord;
        readCoord.X = 6;
        readCoord.Y = 4;
        uint numOfCharsRead = 0;

        ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(stdOut, consoleOutput, length, readCoord, out numOfCharsRead);

        string outputString = consoleOutput.ToString();
        Assert.That(outputString, Is.EqualTo("This is a test title"));

        Curses.EndWin();

        FreeConsole();
    }
```